# How to add second button to ComboBox with custom method?

Tags: wpf, combobox, controltemplate

ComboBox has one button for selection of item. I need to second button for my custom method near first button. How to add it without UserControl?

Answer (score 7):

Control Templates,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084(v=vs.110).aspx

You can re-design a control completely, many good tutorials online

I have always enjoyed Black Wasp tutorial as they take you from A-Z without skipping anything,

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFControlTemplates.aspx

**UPDATE**

ComboBox default template can be found by going to the designer and right cliking the comboBox and selecting Edit Template, then Edit a copy,

Here is the results,

```
   <ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1"
                           Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                           SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="4,4,21,4" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5" />
    <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5" />
    <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070" />
<Geometry x:Key="DownArrowGeometry">M 0 0 L 3.5 4 L 7 0 Z</Geometry>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                     RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                     RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                          Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}" Fill="Black"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#AFAFAF" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder" EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#ABADB3" Offset="0.05" />
    <GradientStop Color="#E2E3EA" Offset="0.07" />
    <GradientStop Color="#E3E9EF" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst" />
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Focusable="false"
                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                     RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                     RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RoundCorners="false"
                                     SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                                     Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                    <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}" Fill="Black"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#AFAFAF" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="Placement" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
               PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}"
               Placement="Bottom">
            <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent"
                                           MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                           MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Placement}">
                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}"
                        BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect"
                                           Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"
                                           Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"
                                           Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" />
                            </Canvas>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"
                                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
        <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                              RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                              RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                 IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                 Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="RenderFocused" TargetName="Border" Value="true" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4" />
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true" />
                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5" />
            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect"
                    Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect"
                    Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,3" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both" />
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition
                            MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"
                            Width="0" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                           IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                           Margin="1"
                           PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}"
                           Placement="Bottom">
                        <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent"
                                                       MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                                       MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                    <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                Width="0">
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect"
                                                       Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"
                                                       Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"
                                                       Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" />
                                        </Canvas>
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"
                                                        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                    </Popup>
                    <ToggleButton BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}" />
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5" />
                        <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer"
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect"
                                Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect"
                                Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<!-- Resource dictionary entries should be defined here. -->
```

First I would find the part in the code that is the drop down button, which from first glance I think is

```
 <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
```

Then I would add another one, with a diff name... and select a horizontal orientation, you could try that as a first step

Comment: @GA Developer, out of interest, what should the second button be doing
? Do you want that to also drop down the comboBox list or something different?

Comment: I'll try to use control template... Second button select most frequent value (or default value).

Comment: I'll give a few goes at trying to do that later today and update soon

Comment: Can anyone offer a decision on control template?

Answer (score 7):

Control templates are probably the only option if you don't want to use UserControl.

First of all the result:

[image: Screenshot]

## Structure

This is not required, but I think it's a great way to implement this without creating a mess.

Create these folders/files in your project:

```
\---Theme
    AppTheme.xaml
    |
    \---Styles
        ComboBox.xaml
```

AppTheme.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Theme/Styles/ComboBox.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    <!-- more styles... -->
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Now add the AppTheme.xaml ResourceDictionary to App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Theme/AppTheme.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

## ControlTemplate

In your XAML Designer Window right click on the ComboBox and select **Edit Template -> Edit A Copy** . If you have created the folders as mentioned in the previous steps you can select **Define in** - **Resource dictionary** and "ComboBox.xaml" should show up.

ComboBox.xaml (modified)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Theme.Styles" xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2">
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFACACAC"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border" Color="#FFABADB3"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDAECFC" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDAEBFC" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFD9D9D9"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF606060"/>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                        <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Glyph}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<!-- Here you can change the name of the template -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
            <!-- Added a column for the new button -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
            <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                        <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        <!-- the new button -->
        <Button Name="MyButton" Grid.Column="2" Padding="10">...</Button>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
            <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                        <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
        <Border x:Name="border" Background="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Background}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,5,3"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I added two comments, which explain what i modified.
Given the template above it is very easy to apply the template to a combobox. Here is a short example:

MainWindow.xaml

```
        <ComboBox Name="combobox" Margin="20" Template="{StaticResource MyComboBoxTemplate}"/>
```

### Accessing the button

Accessing the button seems a bit tricky, but here is one way:

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        combobox.ApplyTemplate();
        
        var template = combobox.Template;
        var bt = (Button)template.FindName("MyButton", combobox);
        bt.Click += Bt_Click;
    }

    private void Bt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("you clicked me!");
    }
```

`combobox.ApplyTemplate()` is neccessary, else you could be looking for something that doesn't exist yet with `template.FindName()`.

Comment: But I need to second button near first button on the right side of the ComboBox.

Comment: Just switch column 0 and column 1 and set column 0 to "*" and column 1 to "auto".

Comment: I updated my answer. Basically your control just needs a name, then you can get a reference to it and do whatever you want.

Comment: it's work :) can you help me with [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236512/can-i-add-second-button-to-the-combobox-using-combobox-resources-in-xaml-with) and then you'll get 50 points!

Comment: I updated the answer again. Have a look at the "Control Template" section, the combobox style should be the same as it was by default.

Comment: I'm sorry but I was blocked... Can you provide minimal code to add new button without change of design of whole combobox? Your code seems too large and I don't need to change anything except the addition of new button. It's my new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236512/can-i-add-second-button-to-the-combobox-using-combobox-resources-in-xaml-with)